# Polynomial of $n-1$ degree

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, binomial-theorem

Given a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$, I want to show that a polynomial of the form 
$$P_n(z)=\sum^n_{i=0} a_iz^i$$
can be decomposed into something like

$$P_n(z)=(z-z_0)\cdot Q_{n-1}(z),$$
where $Q$ is a polynomial  of degree $n-1$ and $P(z_0)=0$.

I started doing the following:

$$P_n(z)=\sum^n_0 a_i((z-z_0)+z_0)^i=\sum^n_{i=0}a_i\sum^i_{k=0}{i\choose k}(z-z_0)^{i-k}z_0^k,$$
but now I don't know how to continue

Comment: that might be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Are you only interested in a proof of existence? Then it would be solved easiely by the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ ist alebraic close and so every polynomial has a solution.

Comment: i just want to know if I can show it the way above with some manipulation

Comment: This is equivalent to proving the fundamental theorem of algebra, so might not be as straightforward as a little manipulation...

Comment: @copper.hat Indeed, if I'm not mistaken, the proof of this theorem is often based in the completeness of the Complex Numbers

Comment: @copper.hat I am using the zero of the function in the computation. I already now the zero is z_0

Comment: Use polynomial division then.

Answer (score 1):

From the Euclidean algorithm applied to polynomials we know that for any $z_0$

$P_n(z) = (z-z_0)Q_{n-1}(z) + R(z)$

where $R(z)$ has degree less than the degree of $z-z_0$ - so in fact $R(z)$ must be a constant $R$ and we have

$P_n(z) = (z-z_0)Q_{n-1}(z) + R$

But if you *know* that $z_0$ is a root of $P_n$ then $P_n(z_0) = 0$ and so $R=0$.

The difficult part is showing the $P_n$ must have at least one root in $\mathbb{C}$. If we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{R}$ then this is not necessarily true because $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed.